# Пронумерованный список

Tags: html

Как сделать чтобы цифры были жирные.
Пример:

> **1.** ABC
>
> **2.** abc
>
> **3.** AaB

Comment: Чувствую что это html-css. Или нет? Ошибаюсь?

Comment: А где они должны стать жирные? Во всем мире что-ли?

Comment: @Barmaley в чем здесь работа за автора? я понимаю "запутывает" можно смело поставить.

Comment: Даже минус жалко поставить...

Answer (score 2):

```
<style>
ol li{
font-weight:bold;
}
ol li span{
font-weight:normal;
}
</style>

<ol>
  <li><span>Coffee</span></li>
  <li><span>Tea</span></li>
  <li><span>Milk</span></li>
</ol>
```

Comment: +, однозначно. Буквально на мгновение не успел.

Comment: Неоднозначно :) Это становится однозначным в редакции @Angry Birds а в авторской версии ужас что.